# Unable to properly use h2 database in Spring framework

Tags: spring, database, spring-boot, h2

I am new to Spring framework as well as H2 databases.
My project is to create a CRUD operation backend to create/read/delete/update people.
I was able to get all my functionalities to work and have tested it with postman, however when I access the database, my table is not being created nor is anything being added to it.

Below is my code:

People.java (where I am trying to create my People Table):

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "People")
public class People {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "people_id", length =20)
    private int peopleID;

    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;
    //setters and getters
```

application.properties:

```
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=

spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto= update
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.datasource.platform=h2
spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always
spring.h2.console.path=/h2
spring.datasource.generate-unique-name=false
```

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
   <parent>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.0</version>
      <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
   </parent>
   <groupId>net.javaguides.springboot</groupId>
   <artifactId>springboot-crud-hibernate-example</artifactId>
   <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
   <name>springboot-crud-hibernate-example</name>
   <description>spring boot crud operations example with hibernate</description>

   <properties>
      <java.version>1.8</java.version>
   </properties>

   <dependencies>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
         <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
         <scope>runtime</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
         <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.jetbrains</groupId>
         <artifactId>annotations</artifactId>
         <version>RELEASE</version>
         <scope>compile</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.jetbrains</groupId>
         <artifactId>annotations</artifactId>
         <version>RELEASE</version>
         <scope>compile</scope>
      </dependency>
   </dependencies>

   <build>
      <plugins>
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
         </plugin>
      </plugins>
   </build>

</project
```

PLEASE any help would be EXTREMELY appreciated!!!!!

I tried changing the configuration multiple times but that would only result in the error
"Whitelabel Error Page This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback." where I wont even have access to the database.

I also tried creating the table from within the database but it acts as a separate entity from my code and none of the functionalities works on it.

Whenever I use the create functionality on postman I get the correct response, but when I go to check my database to check if the person data has been added, nothing is there.

This is a snapshot of my database. Does not have People table created.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nhy5b.png

This is in postman when i create a new person that should be added in the person table.
I get a response.
When I use get to access all the objects I created, all the people I created are displayed as a response. But nothing appears in the DB.

Comment: please make sure you are login at right place to see data in h2 db, I hope you are not getting any exception during save and as per configuration query is enabled ,are you able to see insert query in logs and are you able to fetch table details programatically ?

Comment: i have not done any insert queries. I thought the create functionality would insert the data automatically into the table. Is this incorrect? How do I fetch table details programmatically? I apologize, this is all new to me.

Comment: please follow this :
https://www.bezkoder.com/spring-boot-jpa-h2-example/

simple create object won't getting saved in db, you need to save it.

Comment: yes i am saving after i create the object, when i access all the objects on postman they are all saved. But when i try to access the table in the database it is empty.

Comment: hmm, if you are getting data after save via program , that it should get saved in database. I hope you are aligned with previous example ,then check the h2 db string  during login or please update question with logs when you are creating the new entries.

Comment: I added some additional information. How do i check the h2 db string during login? Your help is extremely appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to run your code and enter the h2 console successfully.

**H2 console**

It seems you are having problem with h2 console, regarding the **application.propeties** you attached, make sure you provide the correct details:

- In a web browser, go to: http://localhost:8080/h2/
- Make sure you're filling the correct input as in the image
- Step 1 - Saved Settings: Generics H2 (Enbedded)
- Step 2 - Setting Name: Generics H2 (Enbedded)
- Step 3 - Driver Class: org.h2.Driver
- Step 4 - JDBC URL : jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
- Step 5 - User Name : sa
- Step 6 - Password: leave in empty
- Step 7 - Click and Test connection and make sure you're getting Green label "Test Successful"
- Step 8 - Connect and check your table

[image: H2 Console setup]

**Check Database**
[image: H2 Console UI]

- Step 1 - Click on the table
- Step 2 - RUN the query

Comment: Thank you so much!!! I spend hours on this and it was my JDBC url which was incorrect. You are a life saver!

Comment: Please mark my answer and close this issue

Answer (score 0):

May be you have not used @transactional annotation over the methods present in dao which are updating , deleting, saving the data to your database because @transaction allow you to make physical changes

Comment: I do have @transactional over the class responsible for the CRUD operations!